# Necessary and sufficient condition differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, finite-differences

I need to prove the equivalence that $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at a given point $a$ if and only if, for every $h$, there exists a linear transformation $A(h)$ such that $$f(a+h)-f(a)=A(h)h$$with $A$ continuous at $0$. For the forward I tried putting $A(h)$ such that $A(h)h=df(a)h+r(h)$ (definition of derivative) put I'm having a hard time proving that is continuous at $0$... Any tips?

Comment: Your proposal for $A(h)$ has to attain that particular value when applied to $h$, but it is only defined for vectors paralle $h$ (not for other vectors) and it is not linear.

Comment: @Thomas I agree, but I can't think of another way to define it...

Comment: Where did you find this characterization? Moreover, do you mean that given $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$, there is $A(h):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ linear or something else?

Comment: @Uskebasi no, A(h) is a matrix. I found this exercise in A Course of Real Analysis vol.2 by Elon Lima

Comment: And, if I understand it correctly, the map $h\mapsto A(h)$ is just continuous for $h$ going to $0$ and is not required to be linear.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:
For the implication:
Define $A(0) = df(a)$ and $A(h)h = df(a)h +r(h)$.
Then $r(h) = (A(h)-A(0))h$, so that 
$$0=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|r(h)|}{|h|}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{|(A(h)-A(0))h|}{|h|}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left|(A(h)-A(0))\frac{h}{|h|}\right|\iff ?A(h)\rightarrow A(0)$$
The converse is easier:
We have that: 
$$f(a+h)-f(a)= A(0)h+(A(h)-A(0))h$$
Notice that $A(0)h$ is linear with $h$, it remains to show that the rest of the RHS tends to zero "faster than $h$". In fact:
$$0\leq\frac{|(A(h)-A(0))h|}{|h|}\leq||(A(h)-A(0))||$$
Now clearly $||A(h)-A(0)||\rightarrow 0$ since $A$ is continuous there, so the result follows.

Comment: not quite sure at the ?